# Array issue in C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am using Turbo c++
I need to shift the all elements which contain 0 to the left
like if array contain following values 20 10 15 7 4 20 2
output must be like this - 0  0  0  10  15  4  2

complete question is first part is to replace the number entered by user with 0 so I enter 20 and they are replaced by 0. 
 original values -> 10 | 20 | 15 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 20 
 I wrote a code for searching and replacing the value which gives output as 10 | 0 | 15 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0. Now I need to collect these 0s at left side means like this 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 15 | 4 | 2

And the code also included which I have written-

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int A[100],no,val,found;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter number of elements you want to insert ";
    cin>>no;
    for(int i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>A[i];
    }

    cout<<"Enter the number you want to search ";
    cin>>val;

    for(int j=0; j<no; j++)
    {
        if(A[j]==val)
            A[j]=0;
    }

    for(int k=0; k<no; k++)
    {
        cout<<A[k]<<"   ";
    }
    getch();
}
```

Need some help.

Comment: I did not understand your sample output

Comment: What have you tried so far? Tell us how you would approach this problem, and which part of it you don't understand.

Comment: Where did all those 0's come from? 20 disappeared, 7 disappeared?!

Comment: It is an IQ quiz guys

Comment: @ZinthosThis is a part of the complete question actual is first part is to replace the number entered by user with 0 so I enter 20 and they are replaced by 0. <br> original values -> 10 | 20 | 15 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 20 <br> I wrote a code for searching and replacing the value which gives output as 10 | 0 | 15 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0. Now I need to collect these 0s at left side means like this 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 15 | 4 | 2

Comment: @user2747954 Ok - could you please edit your question to contain this explanation, and - most importantly - ask a specific question.

Comment: @Hulk I Edited my question as per your suggestion

Comment: @user2747954 Much better. Still not a question, though. I take it that your problem is with extracting the zeroes. Does your task specify whether this has to happen in-place, of is creating a second array acceptable?

Comment: @HulkSimply shift the zeros at left in same array and nonzeros after zeros

Comment: @user2747954 You need 2 nested loops for that. The outer one is looking for zeroes. The inner one swaps the detected zero with the value to its left until the left value is also zero (or the begin of the array is reached)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions:

1. The `#include <conio.h>` is not needed and it is platform specific.
2. The `clrscr()` function call will annoy people trying to help you as
   the prior text is erased.
3. The `no` variable needs to be checked against the capacity of the
   array.
4. Try using `std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');` instead of `getch()`.

To shift the slots with 0, you need to copy values from their old position to the new position, where the first new position is a zero position.

Given:

```
0 -->|10|  
1    |15|  
2    | 0|  
3    | 3|  
4    | 4|
```

The first iteration, swap the 0 in slot 2 with the 15 in slot 2:

```
0 -->|10|  
1    |15| --> | 0|
2    | 0| --> |15|  
3    | 3|
4    | 4|
```

The second iteration, swap the 0 in slot 1 with the 10 in slot 0:

```
0 -->|10| --> | 0|  
1    | 0| --> |10|
2    |15| 
3    | 3|
4    | 4|
```

Keep iterating until the previous slot has a zero value or the previous slot is before the beginning of the array.

*Hint:  you will need two indices, present and previous.*

Edit 1: Example code

```
int swap_index = 0;  
int search_index = 0;  
#define MAX_NUMBERS 6
unsigned int numbers[6] = {10, 15, 0, 3, 4};
for (search_index = 0; search_index < MAX_NUMBERS; ++search_index)
{
  if (numbers[search_index] == 0)
  {
    swap_index = search_index - 1;
    while (swap_index > 0)
    {
      numbers[swap_index + 1] = numbers[swap_index];
      numbers[swap_index] = 0;
      --swap_index;
    }
  }
}
```

This code is a foundation.  There are issues, such as limit checking, which are the responsibility of the reader to fix.

Comment: Not get the desired output I tried like this I entered 10 | 20 | 15 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 20  and replace 20 and output came 10 0 15 4 0 2 0 `int divider = -1;

for (int m = 0; m < no; m++)

{

if (A[m] == 0)

{

// swap A[i] and A[divider+1].

int temp = A[m];

A[m] = A[divider + 1];

A[divider + 1] = temp;

//increment divider.

divider ++;

}

}`

Comment: Are you repeating the swaps in a loop?  Edit your post with your additional code.